# Magento 2.2 Replace Default USPS Shipping Method Names in Cart and Checkout

Tags: magento2.2, shipping-methods

I am trying to override the default USPS shipment method titles in Magento CE 2.2 that show up in the cart and during checkout.  I have created a plugin, USPSChange, and although I'm not getting any errors and I know the plugin is executing, it is not replacing the text.

Does anyone see anything amiss in my code below or have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
namespace Testing\USPSChange\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;

class Method extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method {
 public function afterSetPrice($subject) {
    if ($subject->getMethodTitle() === "Priority Mail 2-Day") {
        $subject->setMethodTitle("Priority Mail");
    } 
    return null;
 }
}
```

[image]